# "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter" on constructor

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

Form 1 is the Main Form, while in Form 2, there is an input to be used in Form 1.

**Form 1:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1(string size)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblsize.Text = size;

    }
}
```

**Form 2:**

```
public void btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //string ukuran = txtsize.Text;
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1(txtsize.Text);
        this.Hide();

    }
```

I then get this error:

> "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'size' of 'Form1.Form1(string)'

Comment: Even though @CodingYoshi gave you the answer, you should have posted **where** the error occurs. Otherwise, how would we possibly know where the fix is required?

Answer (score 2):

In a windows form application project you will have a file named `Program.cs`. In there, you will find a line of code similar to this:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

That is the entry point into your application. Now that you have introduced another constructor in your `Form1` class, the default parameterless constructor is nowhere to be found. Therefore, you get that error.

**Fix**

To fix the error, you may add a parameterless constructor to your `Form1` class like this:

```
public Form1()
{
}
```

That will allow the `Program.cs` class to construct `Form1` during entry, and you will have your other constructor for your needs to pass the `size` to it.

**Additional Explanation**

In C#, if you have a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{ 
    // no constructor
}
```

The compiler will generate one for you by default like this:

```
public class Foo
{ 
    public Foo() { }  
}
```

But as soon as you add a constructor (which you did), then the compiler will not create the default constructor for you anymore (which clearly it did not). Hope the explanation helps.